# Bitmap create null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap, android-view

Here is my xml file : Image view im trying to access

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350dip"
    android:layout_height="400dip"
    android:id="@+id/imgview"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Here is my code.. kindly review the code and let me know where i am doin things wrong i have searched all over the internet just cant try to figure it out how to make bitmap object and draw canvas on image view

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));
}

private static class SampleView extends View {

    private ImageView img;
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
       img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
  //I keep on getting null pointer exception here
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getMeasuredWidth(),img.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        c.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
        paint.setTextSize(40);
        paint.setTextScaleX(1.f);
        paint.setAlpha(0);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        c.drawText("Your text", 30, 40, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 10,10, paint);
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the content view twice. One to a layout. One to your custom view. Whichever is called last is what you're layout will be set as. Since you're setting your custom view last, imgview will not exist in that layout.

Comment: i want to display canvas in the center of layout .. what i am suppose to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a NullPointerException on that line, it means `img` is null, which either means `findViewById(R.id.imgview);` returned null, or onDraw is being executed as part of `super(context);` (not sure if that's the case).

Comment: i tried   `img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` but it didnt work too!

Answer (score 0):

When width or height you want to have in your bitmap exceeds the size of device then you may get this error. You should use `createScaledBitmap`. This will help you.